# How to make app. Icons stay on 12.10 Launch bar

Tags: 12.10

Ubuntu 12.10
How do I make application Icons stay on the launch bar? some stay, but others I have always retrieve from Dash

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it works now. I think the problem is don't always have Right click working (available) on my mouse to lock them. A system error keeps coming up on each reboot, and comes back several times, then asks about video problem, and system hang up, i apported it several times, but then i just have to cancel all the warnings as they come up. Otherwise i would just sit here forever. It seems to go circles, but i am not sure.

Comment: This is not an answer to the problem.  Please delete it if you need to add more detail edit the question.  I suggest you ask a separate question to sort out your problems at start-up.  Include details of your system and the specific errors you are getting.  You can ask here on Ask Ubuntu or on the [Launchpad site](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu)